# Import local copy of a module in Python

Tags: python

Suppose my code lives under a.b.something in production and I have the same path in my cvs repository how do I make python pick the local changes to the module?

In Perl this is possible through the perl -I invocation while running the script. I have searched wide and far and don't find the following alternatives any good:

1. Copying the module into the local folder or
2. Setting the path or something by using os.path, etc.

Looking for something subtle like the Perl invocation or any other easier way of changing the path (without touching the code)

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just install to a new subdirectory of your $PYTHONPATH? Or maybe you could use [VirtualEnv](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/)?

Comment: Do you want to replace the old module in the python process with the newer version of the module? Then you can try `reload`

Comment: Could you elaborate what does "local copy" mean? It should work by default without any flags or changes to the code if you run from the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Python allows you to mess around with the internals of `import`.
You can find more details here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html

Alternatively, modifying `sys.path` seems to work:

```
$ cat some_module.py
def test():
  return "one module"
$ cat other/some_module.py
def test():
  return "the other module"
$ python -c 'import sys; import some_module; print some_module.test()'
one module
$ python -c 'import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "other/"); import some_module; print some_module.test()'
the other module
```